# How to write every raster from a list of rasters?

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing

I have created a list of rasters - "norm" and run a several loops. Now I would like to **write every created raster** from "norm" (containing 1 layer) **into one raster, having its specific name.**

```
# I can get the rasters names
rst.names<-c(1:length(norm))
for(i in 1:length(norm)){
    rst.names1<-names(norm[[i]])
    rst.names[[i]]<-rst.names1
    }
```

To write and save a rasters I have found a very useful answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890369/how-to-write-rasters-after-stacking-them

where they use to respond my question (modified):

```
unst_norm<- unstack(norm)
for(i in 1:lenght(unst_norm)){writeRaster(unst_norm[[i]], file=rst.names[i])}
```

However if I use "unstack" I have this error:

```
Error in stats::as.formula(form) : 
argument "form" is missing, with no default
```

and I can´t find any help for that.

I can use  "unlist" instead of "unstack" but it doesn't seem to work...

but I still get an error:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : Unable to create dataset
```

Please, any ideas where the problem could be? Or, how to automatically **write and save all rasters from raster list?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a list of `raster` objects with equal extent and resolution, it's probably easiest to `stack` them first and then use `writeRaster` with `bylayer=TRUE`.

For example:

```
library(raster)
```

1. Create some dummy data

   ```
   L <- setNames(replicate(3, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))), c('A', 'B', 'C'))

   L

   # $A
   # class       : RasterLayer 
   # dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
   # resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
   # extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
   # coord. ref. : NA 
   # data source : in memory
   # names       : layer 
   # values      : 0.01015837, 0.9958344  (min, max)
   # 
   # 
   # $B
   # class       : RasterLayer 
   # dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
   # resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
   # extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
   # coord. ref. : NA 
   # data source : in memory
   # names       : layer 
   # values      : 0.01501442, 0.9975531  (min, max)
   # 
   # 
   # $C
   # class       : RasterLayer 
   # dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
   # resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
   # extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
   # coord. ref. : NA 
   # data source : in memory
   # names       : layer 
   # values      : 0.01136738, 0.9983568  (min, max)
   ```
2. And stack them and write them out to separate tifs

   ```
   writeRaster(stack(L), names(L), bylayer=TRUE, format='GTiff')
   ```

This will write out the three layers to tifs with names defined by the layer names, i.e. `A.tif`, `B.tif`, and `C.tif`.

Alternatively, if the rasters in the list are not of equal extent/res, you can iterate over the list and write each out in turn:

```
mapply(writeRaster, L, names(L), 'GTiff')
```

I use `mapply` above for convenience, since it allows easy passing of layer names as file names.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to create a simple `for` loop.

```
for (i in 1:length(L)) {
writeRaster(L[[i]], names(L[[i]]), format='GTiff')
}
```

The rasters will be saved in the path you specified as working directory